# what is report error not null @ column while generating report in google dfp api

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-dfp

I'm trying to generate the Google DFP API report on ad_exchange dimension.

please help me to resolve below error

suds.WebFault: Server raised fault:

> [ReportError.NOT_NULL @ columns]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which columns you want. Columns are always required when pulling reports via API.
For entity data only use the PQL tables:
https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/reference/v201208/PublisherQueryLanguageService

Comment: i've specified the columns still i.'m getting the same error
ex: Dimension :AD_EXCHANGE_DATE and columns are [AD_EXCHANGE_MATCHED_REQUESTS,AD_EXCHANGE_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_IMPRESSIONS,AD_EXCHANGE_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_CLICKS,AD_EXCHANGE_AD_REQUESTS,AD_EXCHANGE_ACTIVE_VIEW_MEASURABLE_IMPRESSIONS,
AD_EXCHANGE_ACTIVE_VIEW_VIEWABLE_IMPRESSIONS,AD_EXCHANGE_ACTIVE_VIEW_MEASURED_IMPRESSIONS,AD_EXCHANGE_ACTIVE_VIEW_VIEWED_IMPRESSIONS,AD_EXCHANGE_DEALS_AD_REQUESTS,AD_EXCHANGE_DEALS_BID_RESPONSES,
AD_EXCHANGE_DEALS_MATCH_RATE,AD_EXCHANGE_DEALS_MATCHED_REQUESTS,AD_EXCHANGE_LINE_ITEM_LEVEL_REVENUE] getting error

Comment: please help me to resolve this issue . Thank you in advance